# Do USA J-1 visa questions belong on Expatriates or Travel.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

As of today, Expatriates has [49 questions tagged J-visa](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-visa) while Travel.SE has [57 questions tagged J1-visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j1-visas).

Now, some J-1 visa questions are obviously about travel (eg those relating to airport transfers) and some are obviously about expats (eg those relating to waivers of the 2 year home residency requirement).  But what about the gray areas?

I'm asking because I saw this question was migrated from Expatriates to Travel:
[Where to buy US repatriation and evacuation insurance](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/100141/where-to-buy-us-repatriation-and-evacuation-insurance-only).  The comment about the migration says:

> This isn't an expats question - J1 is a non-immigrant short-term visa. Moving to travel.

The comment implies that all J-1 visa questions should migrate to Travel. So my questions:

- Which site is more appropriate for these questions?
- What is the guideline for migrating them?

EDIT: Another example -- [Health insurance for J visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111184/health-insurance-for-j-visa) has been put on hold at Travel for being off-topic.

More examples: [1](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/135208/is-getting-ds-2019-from-a-third-party-agency-normal)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with J-1 is that it includes a lot of categories ranging from short-term visits to long-term employment, so it doesn't completely fit into either Travel *or* Expatriates.

Here's what I propose:

- **Allow any and all J-1 questions on Expatriates.**  Rationale: Almost any valid question about J-1 can be relevant to long-term uses, even if the original poster's situation is short-term.  Also, Expatriates is generally intended to have a broader scope than Travel, so it makes sense to allow the full spectrum of gray area to exist here.
- **Also allow short-term J-1 questions on Travel.**  Rationale: Although there can be overlap, Travel says it is for questions about short-term trips that don't involve study or employment. Since the site says they are allowed, such questions should be allowed even if they involve a J-1 visa.
- **For long-term J-1 question on Travel, don't close without migrating to Expatriates.**  *Corrolary: don't close J-1 questions on Travel unless you have the system permission to migrate it.* Rationale: It is unrealistic to expect new users to correctly identify where their J-1 question belongs based on the stated guidelines of the two sites. Closing without migrating effectively rejects the question, and few closed questions actually get reposted on the other site. On the other hand, migrating still lets the question be answered, and gives a relatively seamless experience to the end users.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say go ahead and post your question and it will be handled as best as we can. In those 'gray area' type of questions, either site likely has the knowledge base to deal with the topic, though Travel probably gets a bit more traffic.